# Apollo-client useLazyQuery returning undefined on refetch

Tags: javascript, apollo-client

I have a subcomponent Viewer that uses a refetch function passed down to its parent Homescreen.
The lazyQuery in homescreen is structured as follows:

```
const [getById, {loading, error, data, refetch}] = useLazyQuery(GET_BY_ID);
```

This will get an object from my mongoDB by its id, and when I need to call it again and reload data into my custom activeObject variable, I use the follow function:

```
const refetchObjects= async () => {
        const {loading, error, data } = await refetch();
        if (error) { console.log(error);}
        if (data) {
            activeObject = data.getRegionById;
        }
    }
```

However, sometimes the return object of await refetch(); is undefined and I'm not sure why.

Comment: Both of these are in my Homescreen, but I wonder if the homescreen isn't loaded, then the useLazyQuery is never "ran". The homescreen and the call live on separate components/routes in my app, so I feel like this may be a contributing factor.

Comment: have you figured this out? I am having the same issue

Comment: Kind of, I have a workaround in Apollo (as I am using that) where I set my lazyQuery fetchPolicy to cache-and-network. I believe this is caused by my cache not pulling new data correctly. @BrunoBraga